# Speeding up lftp mirroring with many directories

Tags: ftp, wget, lftp

I am trying to mirror a public FTP to a local directory. When I use `wget -m {url}` then wget quite quickly skips lots of files that have been already downloaded (and no newer version exists), when I use `lftp open -u user,pass {url}; mirror` then `lftp` sends `MDTM` for every file before deciding whether to download the file or not. With 2 million+ files in 50 thousand+ directories this is very slow, besides I get error messages that MDTM of directories could not be obtained.

In the manual it says that using `set sync-mode off` will result in sending all requests at once, so that `lftp` doesn't wait for each response. When I do that, I get error messages from the server saying there are too many connections from my IP address.

I tried running `wget` first to download only the newer files, but this does not delete the files which were removed from the FTP server, so I follow up with `lftp` to remove the old files, however `lftp` still sends MDTM on each file, which means that there is no advantage to this approach.

If I use `set ftp:use-mdtm off`, then it seems that `lftp` just downloads all files again.

Could someone suggest the correct setting for `lftp` with large number of directories/files (specifically, so that it skips directories which were not updated, like wget seems to do)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `set ftp:use-mdtm off` and `mirror --ignore-time` for the first invocation to avoid re-downloading all the files.

You can also try to upgrade lftp and/or use `set ftp:use-mlsd on`, in this case lftp will get precise file modification time from the **MLSD** command output (provided that the server supports the command).

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I'm using OSX and `brew install lftp --upgrade` tells me that I have the latest version 4.6.5. I can see from http://lftp.yar.ru that 4.7 is out, so I'll wait until it becomes available via brew.

Comment: Tried with `set ftp:use-mdtm off` and `mirror --ignore-time` and the program checked the directories very quickly. Could you clarify, when you say 'first invocation', what would be the correct setting for the second invocation?

Comment: On second and further invocations `--ignore-time` option won't be needed as the timestamps would already correspond to the displayed timestamps after the first mirror.